# JQuery removing <li> using onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a ul in which I'll add elements using JQuery, I have this

```
function addElement(e) {
    let text = $('#itemToAdd').val();
    let newItem = $('<li>' + text + '</li>');
    let removeBtn = $('<button onclick = "removeElement">X</button>');

    newItem.append(removeBtn);
    $('#shoppingList').append(newItem);
    $('#itemToAdd').val('');
    e.preventDefault();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addBtn").on('click', addElement);
});
```

For removing the elements I have this:

```
function removeElement() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
}
```

The adding function works awesome, but the removing one doesn't.

Comment: can you post your working also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `onclick` then you have to invoke the function with the reference since `this` won't refer to clicked element(refers to `window` object most commonly) and based on that remove that element.

**Element creation:**

```
let removeBtn = $('<button onclick = "removeElement(this)">X</button>');
```

**Function :**

```
function removeElement(ele) {
    $(ele).parent().remove();
}
```

---

Or alternately you can use the existing function but bind event handler using jQuery after element creation.

```
let removeBtn = $('<button>X</button>');
removeElement.click(removeElement);
```

An another option would be [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) which helps to handle events on dynamically created elements.